# Reusable workflow not available after activation

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a SharePoint desinger 2010 Reusable workflow and exported as .wsp file. I import in another site collection via site settings--> Galleries-->Solutions and activated and its activated.

But the Workflow is not available in the List and also i dont see any feature to activate or already activated.

What could be the problem ?..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After activation you should associate the workflow with the lists

[image]

For more details, refer http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1095

Comment: but i dont see the workflow in Sharepoint designer too.

Comment: Did you activate the Workflow from site settings --> site features?

Answer (score 0):

Take a copy of that .wsp file and save in sharepoint features folder 14 hive folder and then activate it to specific list so that it can run independently.